# Diagnostic Software for iPad fingerprint button?

Tags: ipad

I am using an iPad Pro. I have been regularly updating my OS software - beta 13. This week my touch button for fingerprint recognition stopped working. I deleted my old fingerprint file and tried to enter it new. The button would still not pick up the fingerprint. I took it to a repair shop for a quote on a new button, and they said the button is keyed to the processor - they could not just put in a new button. Is there any diagnostics program to check if it is a hardware or software problem?

Comment: Only Apple can change the button & it still work afterwards. It's linked to a Secure Enclave chip, which no-one is going to be giving out the spec to. I'd say your only shot is an Apple Store; sent away for checking/replacement.

Comment: @Tetsujin pls convert this to an answer so we can vote on it

Comment: Not to be rude, but it seems you had your answer already. They replied that they can't replace the button because it is keyed to the hardware and they are correct. You will need to have Apple repair the device. This question made me wonder though if independent repair shops will be able to do this in the future once Apple gets their new repair provider program running: https://9to5mac.com/2019/08/29/apple-independent-repair-provider-program/

Comment: No diagnostic program to verify if it indeed is a hardware failure?

Answer (score 1):

Beta software is not considered stable. The first troubleshooting step should have been removing the beta software. If this did not resolve, completely wiping the device using iTunes > Set up as new (not restored from a backup). If the button does not work after a full wipe and set up as new, it could be indicative of a mechanical failure. Apple can run a diagnotic over the phone or in store to see if the Touch ID module can be detected. More likely the beta software.